# Как удалить элементы из объекта, которые не совпадают при сравнении?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть объект `Obj` из свойством `atr` значением которого является строка. Привожу к числу и сравниваю из переменной `val`, которая является числом от 1 до 5.

Пример: если `val` равна 5, то удаляем все, что меньше или больше 5 из объекта.

Не получается именно удалить элемент из объекта, который отвечает или не отвечает условию сравнения.

Подскажите как такое сделать ?

```
Obj = {
  atr: "10",
  atr: "1",
  atr: "2",
  atr: "11",
  atr: "20",
  atr: "10"
}
```

Comment: одинаковые имена ключей в объекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 delete Obj.attr;
```

Или

```
 delete Obj['attr'];
```

В результате выйдет что-то типо:

```
for (var key in Obj) {
    if (5 !== parseInt(Obj[key])) {
        delete Obj[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: тогда значение `5 lol` останется, может правильнее `if (5 !== +Obj[key])` ?

Comment: В этом случае Вы правы. Но кто знает какие там входящие данные и что получиться должно

Comment: скобка пропущена